# Flutter - How check string value from sharedPreferences

Tags: flutter, dart

How check string value from sharedPreferences list is null or empty? If null or empty go to Login page else print value.

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
final myStringList = sharedPreferences.getStringList('my_sharedPreferences_list') ?? [];

if ( **myStringList[0]  is null or empty**   ) {
  print('> EMAIL not found!');
  Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (context) => Login()
  ));
}
else { print(myStringList[0].toString()); }
```

Comment: If `myStringList` is List, `if(myStringList == null || myStringList.length == 0)`.  If `myStringList` is String, `if(myStringList == null || myStringList.isEmpty)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getStringList` returns nullable list of String
`List<String>?`. You can simply check

```dart
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
final myStringList =
        sharedPreferences.getStringList('my_sharedPreferences_list');

if(myStringList==null ){ 
 print('> EMAIL not found!');
  Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (context) => Login()
  ));
}
else { print(myStringList[0].toString()); }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if your list is null  or empty using this command `myStringList == null || myStringList.isEmpty` .

`||` indicates `or` operator

Answer (score 0):

You have two way to check null
The first likes Yeasin `if(myStringList==null )`
and the second set default value when you get like this

```
final myStringList =
    sharedPreferences.getStringList('my_sharedPreferences_list') ?? '';
```

Then check with empty or not empty

```
if (myStringList.isEmpty) {}
if (myStringList.isNotEmpty) {}
```